# Error al ejecutar JSON.parse(); "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, sweetalert

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de como crear una tienda virtual con PHP y al ejecutar el submit me aparece el error del título. Estuve revisando el código y hasta moficandolo como por ejemplo cambiando tableRoles.api().ajax.reload(func... por tableRoles.ajax.reload(func... pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Lo que busco es que se ejecute el plugin de Sweet Alerts que lo tengo bien enlazado (el script del plugin) pero resulta que si bien no me aparece la alerta, si se ejecuta el submit, es decir, se guardan correctamente los datos en phpMyAdmin

JS

```
let formRol =  document.getElementById('formRol');
    formRol.onsubmit = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let strNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
        let strDescripcion = document.getElementById('txtDescripcion').value;
        let intStatus = document.getElementById('listStatus').value;
        if(strNombre=='' || strDescripcion=='' || intStatus==''){
            swal("Atnción", "Todos los campos son obligatorios.", "error");
            return false;
        }
        let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        let ajaxUrl = baseUrl+'/Roles/setRol';
        let formData = new FormData(formRol);
        request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
        request.send(formData);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                let objData =  JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                if(objData.status){
                    $('#modalFormRol').modal("hide");
                    formRol.reset();
                    swal("Roles de usuario", objData.msg, "success");
                    tableRoles.api().ajax.reload(function(){
                    });
                } else {
                    swal("Error", objData.msg, "error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PHP (el array del JSON)

```
public function setRol(){
            $strRol = strClean($_POST['txtNombre']);
            $strDescripcion = strClean($_POST['txtDescripcion']);
            $intStatus = intVal($_POST['listStatus']);
            $requestRol = $this->model->insertRol($strRol, $strDescripcion, $intStatus);

            if($requestRol > 0){
                $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Datos guardados correctamente.');
            } else if ($requestRol == 'exist'){
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => '¡Atención! El rol ya existe.');
            } else {
                $arrResponse = array("status" => false, 'msg' => 'No es posible almacenar los datos actualmente.');
            }

            echo json_decode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            die();
        }
```

HTML (la función en php representa la ruta a los assets)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= media(); ?>/js/plugins/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Link del video por si acaso

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX-HswHQ_no&list=PL3b9xmg86NTKWP3Xzu-1DCwaeO5sftK4V&index=35&ab_channel=AbelOS

Comment: El origen del problema no lo estás incluyendo en la pregunta: el JSON que estás enviando tiene un problema de formato. Podrías incluirlo en la pregunta?

Comment: Fijate si antes de devolver el json no te manda un error. Si es así, ahí esta el lio, porque lo devuelto no es todo envuelto como json

Answer (score 0):

En el array php en vez de json_decode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); proba json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Gracias, ahora si me funciona!